# LINQ search on multiple columns and determine on what column it matched on

Tags: c#, linq

I'm searching on multiple columns I want to determine which column matched my search text on the results.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
var names = new[]
{
    new { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Doe", NickName = "Bobby", },
    new { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Doe", NickName = "Joey", },
    new { FirstName = "Cookie", LastName = "Monster", NickName = "Rick", },
    new { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Magoo", NickName = "George", },
    new { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Hsmil", NickName = "Masrkie", },
    new { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Doe", NickName = "James", },
};
```

And a query like this:

```
string searchText = "James";

var result = names
        .Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchText)
            || x.LastName.Contains(searchText)
            || x.NickName.Contains(searchText));
```

I will get two results:

| FirstName | LastName | NickName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | Doe | Bobby |
| Joe | Doe | James |

Is there a way I can determine from my result who matched on what column?

I Googled this reasonably, a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string searchText = "James";

var result =
    names
        .Select(x => new
        {
            name = x,
            matches =
                new[]
                {
                    x.FirstName.Contains(searchText) ? "FirstName" : null,
                    x.LastName.Contains(searchText) ? "LastName" : null,
                    x.NickName.Contains(searchText) ? "NickName" : null,
                }
                    .Where(y => y != null)
                    .ToArray(),
        })
        .Where(x => x.matches.Any());
```

With the very convenient sample data in your question, I get this:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! What tool did you use to visualize the result like that?